# ASP.net Image retrieved from database not show in Chrome and Firefox except IE and Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a food ordering web page. I have saved the images in database as varbinary. It correctly displays on IE and Edge. But not in Firefox and Chrome. (I am seeing a torn page icon instead where the image should be).

I have write this code in the ImageLoad.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ImageLoad : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
        {
            string strQuery = "select Name, contentType, Data, description from food where fid=@id";
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch
            {
                dt = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sda.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
            if (dt != null)
            {


                try
                {
                    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";

                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And included below code in the desserts.aspx page

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" Font-Names = "Arial" Caption = "Available Food" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField = "fID" HeaderText = "Item ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField = "fID" DataImageUrlFormatString = "/ImageLoad.aspx?ImageID={0}" ControlStyle-Width = "200" ControlStyle-Height = "200" HeaderText = "Preview">
<ControlStyle Height="150px" Width="150px"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ImageField>
                </Columns> 
                  <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                  <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                  <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                  <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
             </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the preview.. I have attached the preview below.
[Image -for IE OK but Firefox cannot display that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ElbK.jpg)

Here is the db contents > [DB content image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VVFA.jpg)

Comment: can you share the image name with the extension that is saved in your database?

Comment: Yes,, Image name is (there are  couple of images) - blueberry-lemon-napoleon-8.jpg and the extension is .jpg

Comment: The table named, Food has name and contentType fields.

Comment: name -  blueberry-lemon-napoleon-8.jpg
contentType - image/jpg

Comment: Can you check the console for any load errors, firefox does not like if content type is anything unexpected. Also, right click on the image and open it in a new tab and check the headers and the response.

Comment: Also, why is there two `content-disposition` headers?

Comment: Thanks !! You are awesome Mathew

Comment: I don't know what it does .. but I have removed the second `content-disposition` named  `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString());`

Comment: Thank you @Mathew. Now Firefox shows the images..

Comment: You can safely remove both of them if you don't want the image to be downloaded instead of being displayed in the browser when the image url is directly accessed.

Comment: @Mathew , I have commented both and .. as you said I can still see the Images. What is the difference between Keeping one and removing that??

Comment: @Mathew, Then what is the reason to add `content-disposition` ?

Comment: @Mathew, Please add your Answer ... I will accept it.. (I am new to StackOverflow and this is my first question)

Comment: @Matthew , I have understood.. It won't download when directly accessed that image url when we remove all `content-disposition` s. It only views it !!

Comment: @Senura, exactly. Since you have posted the correct answer, that is fine. I've upvoted it, you might want to add your last comment into your answer so that future visitors will know why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what it does .. but I have removed the second `content-disposition` named `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString());`

Now Firefox shows the Images. Credit goes to @Mathew

Comment: I have understood.. It won't download when directly accessed that image url when we remove all `content-disposition` s. It only views it !!